# Auto download file from URL cross-browser

Tags: javascript, angular, file, download

I am trying to download a file from URL which my BE provides to me.
I have endpoint which requires file GUID and one-time access token and returns file with header

```
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="testfile.txt"
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

and URL looks something like this and it is built dynamically by RXJS so I cant just assign in into HTML with download attribute

```
`/document/${guid}/download?token=${token}`
```

I have found many threads with this topic, but most of them recommend using window class functions such as open, assert, location, etc. Which are really not working across all browsers in the way I want - automatically start downloading the file without opening extra tab, etc. I have also found solution with DOM manipulation such as appendChild with  element and given URL and removing it afterwards, but this solution seems ugly to me.

So my question is, is there any elegant way how could I force browser to download a file without opening it in extra tab, without DOM manipulation and cross-browser (because download attribute is not working on Safari) or importing 3rd party library?